# Can't write string to text file two times

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, writealltext

i have a two strings with a c# program named eMail & password and i have a regex that check if the text match or not, if the two strings are verified it will save these two strings in 2 different textfiles this is my code:

```
        string eMail = textBox1.Text;
        string password = textBox2.Text;
        Regex email_Regex = new Regex(@"^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$");
        Match email_Match = email_Regex.Match(eMail);
        Regex password_Regex = new Regex("^.{4,20}$");
        Match password_Match = password_Regex.Match(password);
        if (!email_Match.Success)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this,
                "Please Enter A Valid Email Adress !",
                "Error While Connecting !",
                MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel,
                MessageBoxIcon.Error,
                MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button3);
        }
        else if (!password_Match.Success)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this,
                "Please Enter A Valid Password !",
                "Error While Connecting !",
                MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel,
                MessageBoxIcon.Error,
                MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button3);
        }


        else if (password_Match.Success)
        {
            File.WriteAllText(@"D:\Password.txt", password);
        }

        else if (email_Match.Success)
        {
             File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Email.txt", eMail);
        }
```

when I debug and i test my program only one textfile is created it the first one ( only the Password.txt )
Any solution ?

Comment: Only one branch in an if/elseif/elseif will run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change it to:

```
    if (!email_Match.Success)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(this,
            "Please Enter A Valid Email Adress !",
            "Error While Connecting !",
            MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel,
            MessageBoxIcon.Error,
            MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button3);
    }
    else if (!password_Match.Success)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(this,
            "Please Enter A Valid Password !",
            "Error While Connecting !",
            MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel,
            MessageBoxIcon.Error,
            MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button3);
    }

    else
    {
       File.WriteAllText(@"D:\Password.txt", password);
       File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Email.txt", eMail);
    }
```

because only one else if can be executed, in code above if email and password are correct it will write to both files.

You **don't need to** check if match is successfull again, because you checked if it is not succesfull before :)

Answer (score 1):

By the time you've got there, you know both matches are success. Just use:

```
else (password_Match.Success)
{
    File.WriteAllText(@"D:\Password.txt", password);
    File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Email.txt", eMail);
}
```

Comment: you don't need to write `if` -> it's sure that it's successfull match :)

Answer (score 0):

just change the code in the last 2 "else if" statement

you should remove the "else" from the code

That's all